# JavaFX setText() NullPointerException even though I have set controller and fxml tags

Tags: java, javafx, null, fxml

I am trying to fill data into my new scene when I switch to it. The user logs in (which is working because if I toString() him I get everything I need). When I call setText() on the JFXTextField for example, it does not work.

This is my controller. Updatehome is called when I switch to this scene

```
public class DashboardController {

    @FXML JFXTextField txtGastDashboardSuchfeld;
    @FXML Label lblGastDashboardNachnameVorname;
    @FXML JFXTextField txtGastHomeVorname;
    @FXML JFXTextField txtGastHomeNachname;
    @FXML JFXTextField txtGastHomeSteuernummer;
    @FXML JFXTextField txtGastHomeAusweisnummer;
    @FXML JFXTextField txtGastHomeEmail;
    @FXML JFXPasswordField pwfGastHomePasswort;


    public void updateHome() {
        if(Main.user == null) {
            Controller.errorMessage("Fataler Fehler", "User konnte nicht aufgelöst werden!");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(Main.user.toString());

        lblGastDashboardNachnameVorname.setText(Main.user.getVollername());
        txtGastHomeVorname.setText(Main.user.getVorname());
        txtGastHomeNachname.setText(Main.user.getNachname());
        txtGastHomeSteuernummer.setText(Main.user.getSteuernummer());
        txtGastHomeAusweisnummer.setText(Main.user.getAusweisnummer());
        txtGastHomeEmail.setText(Main.user.getEmailAdresse());
        pwfGastHomePasswort.setText(Main.user.getPasswort().toString());
    }

}
```

In my Main class I have this (Scenes are being loaded)

```
public static Controller controller;
public static DashboardController dashboardController;

public static Person user = null;

public static Stage window;

public static TreeMap<String, Scene> scenes = new TreeMap<>();
public static ArrayList<Scene> history = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {     
    window = primaryStage;
    controller = new Controller();
    dashboardController = new DashboardController();
    loadScenes();
}
```

This is a snippet from the method that loads the scenes into my treemap

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
        try {
            if(sceneName.contains("dashboard")) {
                loader.setController(dashboardController);
            } else
                loader.setController(controller);

            Parent parent = (Parent)loader.load();

            scenes.put(sceneName, new Scene(parent));
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the null pointer exception?

Comment: Can you add the fxml file?

Comment: Given the code snippets you've posted, you might also want to check that the FXML file that is being loaded is the one you think it is... Are you sure you are not setting the controller to the `dashboardController` for the wrong FXML file?

Comment: @James_D line `txtGastHomeVorname.setText(Main.user.getVorname());` in `updateHome()` is throwing the exception.


@HamishD This is the FXML file I am loading https://pastebin.com/MAbbpxnq

The dashboard controller is only set when I am switching to the dashboard. The weird thing is that this line `lblGastDashboardNachnameVorname.setText(Main.user.getVollername());` works without problems. All the others don't.

I didn't want to post too much code to keep it a bit more clean but if you need it just tell me.

Comment: Okay so after taking a close look at my fxml file I found the reason for the null objects.

I used scene builder to create these and under `fx:id` I set the correct names. Still, when I check the file, they are nowhere to be found. If I manually add those tags everything starts to work.
So my question would have to be why scenebuilder doesn't save the fx:ids